# jQuery map does not work with json array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a $.post jQuery call that calls a php file. The file then returns a JSON encoded array. Then, the array is mapped to edit some of the data in the array. However, I get the error `arr.map is not function`.

Here is the array being passed in the $.post call.

```
[{"set":"Alpha","key":"256"},
{"set":"Omega","key":"671"},
{"set":"Theta","key":"762"},
{"set":"Beta","key":"462"}]
```

Here is the map function.

```
idHash = {'Alpha': '1', 'Beta': '2', 'Theta': '3', 'Omega': '4'};
var arr = arr.map(function(item){
    item.set = idHash[item.set]
    return item;
})
```

After the map function, the array should look like this.

```
[{"set":"1","key":"256"},
{"set":"4","key":"671"},
{"set":"3","key":"762"},
{"set":"2","key":"462"}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The array you are executing `.map()` would need to be a jquery object. If you set the result data equal to a jquery array with `$` affixed to it you should able to use the jquery map utility. You can also use `$.map(array, function(item){});`,

https://jsfiddle.net/62v2a0cw/1/

```
idHash = {'Alpha': '1', 'Beta': '2', 'Theta': '3', 'Omega': '4'};

var arr = $.map(idHash, function(item){
    item.set = idHash[item.set];
    console.log(item);
    return item;
});
```

Please see jsFiddle link. Let me know if that helps. That is simply to assist with `.map()`. If you want to create an array of JSON objects, you could use jQuery `.each()` and push each key, value pair accordingly to an array. You could use manipulate the value on each iteration accordingly to your needs. Based on your comments, assuming the JSON you are working with identified by `idHash` is equal to `{'Alpha': '1', 'Beta': '2', 'Theta': '3', 'Omega': '4'}`

```
arr = [];
idHash = {'Alpha': '1', 'Beta': '2', 'Theta': '3', 'Omega': '4'};

$.each(idHash, function(key, value){
    // do whatever with the value before setting
    value *= 15;
    arr.push({"set": key, "key": value });
});    
console.log(arr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/62v2a0cw/2/

Comment: I get this error. `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '2113' in` and then it lists the array.

Comment: What is idHash referring to? If you replace that with a `console.log(item);` the .map() works.

Comment: `.map()` requires either a jquery object using the $ or to call it such as `$.map(array, function(){});`. The error may be just with the `item.set` line of code.

Comment: `idHash = {'Alpha': '1', 'Beta': '2', 'Theta': '3', 'Omega': '4'};`

Comment: The idHash is supposed to be updating the values under the set key in this array.
`[{"set":"Alpha","key":"256"},
{"set":"Omega","key":"671"},
{"set":"Theta","key":"762"},
{"set":"Beta","key":"462"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Signature of [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) is:

> jQuery.map( array, callback )

So, you can try this:

```
var data = [{"set":"Alpha","key":"256"},
{"set":"Omega","key":"671"},
{"set":"Theta","key":"762"},
{"set":"Beta","key":"462"}];

$.map(data, function(elem){
    elem.set = newValue;
    elem.key = newValue;
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bh98zj4/2/).